Table list doesn't update inside async timer
I'm rather new to Blazor, but not to OO languages
I've got a web service that has a controller that returns requests from a repository
I have a UI service that is independent and calls the web service
I'm trying to update a table periodically with the results of the get from the web service
@page "/"

@using System.Timers
@using WebServices 

@inject StatusService WebService // Has a httpClient to call web service
@inject IConfiguration Configuration

<h4>Status Viewer</h4> 

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Last Update</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
   
    <tbody>
        @if (StatusList != null)
        {
            @foreach (var status in StatusList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@status.Name</td>
                    <td>@status.Status</td>
                    <td>@status.Timestamp</td>                   
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

 
@code
{
    public IEnumerable<Status> StatusList { get; set; }

    private int UIReloadTime;
    private const int MINUTE_IN_MILLISECONDS = 60000;
    private System.Timers.Timer Timer { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        UIReloadTime = int.Parse(Configuration.GetValue<string>("ui:ReloadTime"));
        await UpdateStatus();

        Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        Timer.Interval = (UIReloadTime * MINUTE_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        Timer.Elapsed += OnElapsed;
        Timer.Enabled = true;
        Timer.Start();
    } 

    private async void OnElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        await UpdateStatus();
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private async Task UpdateStatus()
    {
        StatusList = await WebService.GetStatus();
    }
}

I get a valid value during the init process, but after that, nothing.
I know it is something to do with the rerendering, but I do not know how to trigger it that is different to how I am doing it now
I am using the server side rendering, not sure if I'm trying to do a WASM thing with the server rendering
I've tried the PeriodicTimer, the Threading.Timer and been trying things for about 2 days now and nothing works
I've also attempted to implement IDisposable with the Timer types, but dispose is always called
EDIT: I've also since tried making a new WASM app and transferring across the attempts. It still doesn't work. I am officially stumped
EDIT_2: It was the application having the Interactivity Location set to per page/component that was causing the issue

I just tried this in a sample app and it worked as expected. Obviously I don't have your web service so I just mocked up an update and threw an await Task.Delay(3000); in there to simulate a little latency when retrieving the list. At first I thought there may be an issue with calling the await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged) from inside an async void method, but that doesn't seem to be an issue. I, too, am stumped why it's not working for you. One thing I am curious about: how are you able to have a Status class with a Status property? I wouldn't think the compiler would allow that.

@Lex lol, works for me strikes again. I've changed some of the code to be more generic, as its for work. So in the real setup, there is no Status.Status

@Lex What template did you use when creating the sample app?

It's a super old test bed project I use so it was before the different interactive templates were released. Just a standard .Net 6 Blazor Server app.

Template: Blazor Web App - InteractiveServer - Global Interactivity
I've refactored your code a little to create a Minimal Reproducible Example.  I've also changed over to using the System.Threading.Timer and TimeSpan to represent time.
My Data object and Service.
public record StatusData(string Name, string Status, DateTimeOffset Timestamp);

public class StatusService
{
    private List<StatusData> statusData = new List<StatusData>()
    {
        new("France", "Loaded", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-3)),
        new("Spain", "Loaded", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-2)),
        new("Portugal", "Loaded", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1)),
    };

    public async ValueTask<IEnumerable<StatusData>> GetStatus()
    {
        // Fake an async API call
        statusData.Add(new("Me", "Loading", DateTimeOffset.Now));
        await Task.Yield();
        return statusData.AsEnumerable();
    }
}

And DI registration:
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddScoped<StatusService>();

var app = builder.Build();

And my reformatted page:
@page "/"

@using System.Threading
@inject StatusService WebService
@implements IDisposable

<h4>Status Viewer</h4>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Last Update</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @if (StatusList != null)
        {
            @foreach (var status in StatusList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@status.Name</td>
                    <td>@status.Status</td>
                    <td>@status.Timestamp</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>


@code
{
    public IEnumerable<StatusData> StatusList { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<StatusData>();

    private TimeSpan _timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    private Timer? _timer { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await UpdateStatus();

        // Kick off the first one off timer
        _timer = new Timer(this.OnTimerElapsed, null, _timeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
    }

    private async void OnTimerElapsed(object? state)
    {
        await UpdateStatus();
        // Creates a new one off timer once we have the current data
        // prevents any thread and data conflicts
        _timer = new Timer(this.OnTimerElapsed, null, _timeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private async Task UpdateStatus()
    {
        StatusList = await WebService.GetStatus();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}

GitHub Repo is temporarily here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO78788856

I've tested it as it is, and it works.
I have no idea what is really different, as I've tried a lot of this already.
I'll give this a go in the work environment and let you know :)

You need to provide a [MRE] of a not working version.  The problem is often in the bits of code you don't show [because you don't believe they're relevant] in a question.

So, it was the interactive server being set to global that fixed it. I had to create a new app and apply everything I'd done before, plus a couple of changes you put here just to ensure all the settings were set correctly. Thank you very much

As you weren't setting the render mode in the page, I guessed you were setting it globally.

I'm new to Blazor, didn't really understand how that worked. I have much better clarity now
